# What does overclocking do to me?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

I enabled one of the experimental augments and now my augments screen indicates Jensen is running at 150%

I assume there's some kind of negative penalty for this.  **What happens if I don't shut off another augment to bring this back down to 100%?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've recently found this video that explains different stages of overclocking and their consequences.

Summary:

**150%** - you'll experience aug glitches similar to those you had before coming to Koller (like radar reseting)

**300%** - you'll start see some strange visual artificts (like those you could see in real world if you video card malfunctions). Some augs could backfire, killing you (explosive nano blades on video)

**350%** - you'll experience periodical resets of your vision. After several of them you'll have an infolink call with Koller and he'll give you a final wanring to reduce the overclock

**450%** - you'll experience a reboot. During it you won't see anything on your HUD, you won't be able to use any augs. After reboot is done (around 15 seconds) you'll have an infolink call with Koller where he blames you for not being careful and you discover that one of your regular augs has shutdown permanently i.e. it will be marked the same way if you'd disable it manually but this time there won't be any way to re-enable it. This will effectively reduce the overclock to 400% so you will no longer lose anything but all the above glithces will remain

Answer (score 1):

According to this website article they state that leaving Jensen overclocked for too long will "begin to drain energy faster, cause health loss, and other negative effects."

One other negative side effect the game mentions is that it will cause glitches, most likely on your HUD, though I cannot say for sure. I doubt that it would cause glitches with your augments themselves but again I can't say for sure.

http://www.shacknews.com/article/96445/deus-ex-mankind-divided---understanding-augmentation-overclock

The game instructs you to disable augments to prevent the overheating but there is a sidequest obtained from Koller, which upon completion will allow you to not have to worry about the whole overheating issue and will let you have all augs available to upgrade.

Comment: That's rather vague, I was hoping for more specific details.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't offer anything else, it's all I managed to find about it and from what I've learnt on my own so far.